# Python function execution on iterator till empty

Tags: python, pandas, csv, iterator

I have an iterator and I want to execute function on the iterator till the iterator is empty. Is my approach below correct or is there better practice?

```
import pandas as pd

df_iter = pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize=some_chunksize_value)

def some_function(data):
    try:
        do sth with data.__next__()
        some_function(data)
    except StopIteration:
        do sth here
        return True

some_function(df_iter )
```

Comment: `next(df_iter)` perhaps, also unsure if `pd.read_csv` gives you an iterator

Comment: just iterate over `df_iter` using a loop (`for item in df_iter`), you don't need recursion for this.

Comment: it gives me an iterator with chunksize. yeah, next or __next__() but how to check if iterator is empty complete execution?

Comment: I want to avoid for loops or if statement or any other nested logic.

Comment: "I want to avoid for loops". Why? It's almost impossible to write any significant program without them. And isn't recursion more nested than loops anyway?

Comment: Should you decide to use next(iterator), note that there’s two ways to check for “emptiness”. First, a next call will hit an exception StopIteration like you have. Secondly, you could add a second parameter to your next statement, like next(iterator, None) which will instead of throwing the exception produce the second parameter when the iterator has nothing more to produce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a for loop. This will automatically call next() and halt on a StopIteration without you having to do anything.

```
for item in df_iter:
    #do something with data here
```

You don't need to use recursion for this, and recursion is especially unsuitable if there is any chance your iterator has more than 1000 values. Then you'll crash with "maximum recursion depth exceeded" before reaching the end.

---

If you're in a functional-paradigm mood, you can use `map` to apply a function to an iterable without requiring an explicit for loop.

```
map(do_thing, df_iter)
```

This will return another iterable that calls `do_thing` on each element of `df_iter` as you iterate over it. (Or, in Python 2.7, it calls `do_thing` on each element immediately and returns a list of all the results)

This approach is relatively rare, since for loops, list comprehensions, and/or generator expressions can do the same thing with arguably simpler syntax.

Comment: Good catch, didn't see the recursion there, although doing `next(df_iter)` in a try catch is extra work as well